# How to get rows of Data from Multiple Tables using LinQ To Entities

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I am using dbcontext Code first to get a query base on this condition for the Classes (tables) below:

Creator != null && ArticleAttached != null && !IsCancelled

```
var ArticleStudentLiked = dbcontext.LearningActivites
  .Where(la => la.Creator != null && la.ArticleAttached != null && !la.IsCancelled)
  .Sum(la => la.ArticleAttached.StudentsLiked.Count);

  var NewsArticleComment = dbcontext.LearningActivites
  .Where(la => la.Creator != null && la.ArticleAttached != null && !la.IsCancelled)
  .Sum(la => la.ArticleAttached.Comments.Count);
```

The following Methods only return count for:

- ArticleStudentLiked
- ArticleComment

I need to get rows of record from the Queries into a single collection which I can pass to View to display line by line

like this :

Article Title, No. of Likes, No. Of Comments

How to use LinQ to Get these : Article Title,No. Of Like , No. of Comment

```
Classes:


 public class LearningActivity
 {
   public virtual ArticleCreator Creator { get; set; }        
   public virtual ArticleCreator EditedBy { get; set; }        
   public virtual Teacher CreatedByTeacher { get; set; }   
   public virtual Article ArticleAttached { get; set; }   
   public virtual Article ArticleAttachedByOther { get; set; } 
   public bool IsCancelled { get; set; }
 }


 public class Article 
 {
   public string ArticleTitle {get;set;}
   public virtual IList<Teacher> TeachersLiked { get; set; }
   public virtual IList<Student> StudentsLiked { get; set; }
   public virtual IList<ArticleComment> Comments { get; set; }
 }


 public class Student
 {
   public virtual IList<ArticleCommentStudent> Comments { get; set; }
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: which classes are you trying to combine ?

Comment: The classes are the tables and they are linked. I need to do this: get the first article, then sum up all the likes and comments for this article. How to in LinQ to Entities?

Comment: does your Article have class ID property. To implement condition in where clause

Comment: did my answer work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this

```
// LikeCount is total of Teacher and Student Likes 
// and where clause can be added before Select
var result = dbcontext.Classes
            .Select(x=> new { ArticleTitle = x.ArticleTitle, 
                              LikeCount = x.TeachersLiked.Count() + x.StudentsLiked.Count(), 
                              CommentCount= x.Comments.Count }).First();
```

Comment: Hi, It should work. I think your solution should work. I split the problem into 2 parts. Now I got the first part as I tried to see how I can get the data. I need to get data from other table to form one single collection.  But I dont know how to link it to second part. I will give  you the link later.

Comment: here the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44407217/how-to-joint-two-set-of-retrieved-data-using-linq-to-entities  Thank you.