# How to joint two set of retrieved data using LinQ To Entities

Tags: entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I am using dbcontext Code first to get a query base on this condition for the Classes (tables) below:

Creator != null && ArticleAttached != null && !IsCancelled

Problem :

How to get data from the classes (tables) and show

Article Title, No. of Likes, No. Of Comments,  Total Assigned, TotalResponded

```
A) I use dbcontext as follows:

  var ListArticles = dbcontext.LearningActivites
   .Where(la => la.Creator != null && la.ArticleAttached != null && !la.IsCancelled)
   .Select(la =>
      new
      {
        Id = la.Id,
        Title = la.ArticleAttached.ArticleTitle,
        CreatedWhen = la.ArticleAttached.CreatedAt,
        TTLComment = la.ArticleAttached.Comments.Count,                
        TTLOfLikes = la.ArticleAttached.StudentsLiked.Count + la.ArticleAttached.TeachersLiked.Count

      });

This will get :

 Article Title, Total of Likes, total Comment
```

**B) How to get : Total Assigned  and Total Responded base on the classes below?**

```
 var TotalAssigned = dbcontext.LearningActivites
 .Where(la => la.Creator != null && la.ArticleAttached != null && !la.IsCancelled) 
 .Sum(la => la.ClassesAssigned.SelectMany(a => a.LearningActivitiesAssigned.LongCount));
```

**C) How to joint the result from A + B ?**

to show 
Article Title, No. of Likes, No. Of Comments, Total Assigned, TotalResponded

**Classes:**

```
 public class LearningActivity
 {
   public virtual ArticleCreator Creator { get; set; }        
   public virtual ArticleCreator EditedBy { get; set; }        
   public virtual Teacher CreatedByTeacher { get; set; }   
   public virtual Article ArticleAttached { get; set; }   
   public virtual Article ArticleAttachedByOther { get; set; } 

   public virtual IList<Class> ClassesAssigned { get; set; }
   public virtual IList<Group> GroupsAssigned { get; set; }

   public bool IsCancelled { get; set; }
 }


 public class Article 
 {
   public string ArticleTitle {get;set;}
   public virtual IList<Teacher> TeachersLiked { get; set; }
   public virtual IList<Student> StudentsLiked { get; set; }
   public virtual IList<ArticleComment> Comments { get; set; }
 }


 public class Student
 {
   public virtual IList<ArticleCommentStudent> Comments { get; set; }
 }



 public class Class 
 {
   public virtual School School { get; set; }
   public virtual IList<Student> Students { get; set; }
   public virtual IList<LearningActivity> LearningActivitiesAssigned { get; set; }

 }

 public class Group
 {
  public virtual School School { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<Student> Students { get; set; }
  public virtual ApplicationUser Creator { get; set; }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you calculate TotalResponded in question

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this to sum of Assigned

`TotalAssigned = la.ClassesAssigned.Sum(x => x.LearningActivitiesAssigned.LongCount)`

and `.GroupBy(la => la.ArticleAttached.ArticleTitle)`

```
var ListArticles = dbcontext.LearningActivites
   .GroupBy(la => la.ArticleAttached.ArticleTitle)
   .Where(la => la.Creator != null && la.ArticleAttached != null && !la.IsCancelled)
   .Select(la =>
      new
      {
        Id = la.Id,
        Title = la.ArticleAttached.ArticleTitle,
        CreatedWhen = la.ArticleAttached.CreatedAt,
        TTLComment = la.ArticleAttached.Comments.Count,                
        TTLOfLikes = la.ArticleAttached.StudentsLiked.Count + la.ArticleAttached.TeachersLiked.Count
        TotalAssigned = la.ClassesAssigned.Sum(x => x.LearningActivitiesAssigned.LongCount)
      });
```

Comment: TotalAssigned is a total number of students for the Article. This need to be calculated separately and can not include inside the Single linQ statement. Because I need to joint A + B into a ViewModel. Thanks for helping.